# A chain related to Automorphism groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

This question is about finite groups.

Let a group $G_0=1$. Suppose $Aut G_1=G_0$. Then $G_1$ is isomorphic to either $1$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2$. To make $|G_1|$ as large as possible, Take $G_1=\mathbb{Z}_2$. Define $G_1=\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Similarly take $AutG_2=G_1$ and let $|G_2|$ take the greatest possible value, so $G_2=\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Take $AutG_{n+1}=G_n$ and let $|G_{n+1}|$ take the greatest possible value.

Questions:

1. What are $G_3$ and $G_4$? I really struggle to find them.
2. Is the sequence $G_n$ well defined?
3. Who can find a necessary and suficient condition on the value of $n$, making $Aut\mathbb{Z}_n=\mathbb{Z}_{n-1}$?

Comment: Say explicitly that you assume groups are finite.

Comment: 3 is very easy: $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z_n)$ has $\varphi(n)<n$ elements so it never happens. If, as I suspect, you did mean $n-1$ instead of $n+1$ there then this happens iff $n$ is prime.

Comment: Yes. It's n-1, not n+1.

Answer (score 2):

For convenience, I put the answer again here. Thanks Dietrich Burde.

[1][Some Finite Groups Which Are Rarely Automorphism Groups](http://www.jstor.org/stable/20489177?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

Theorem: There is no group $G$ such that $Aut(G)$ is abelian of order $p^5$,
$p^6$ or $p^7$ for a prime $p$.

Theorem: There is no group $G$ such that $Aut(G)$ has order $p^4$, for odd prime $p$.

More recently, Ban an Yu showed:

Theorem: there is no group $G$ such that $Aut(G)$ is an abelian $p$-group of order $n<p^{12}$, where $p>2$ is a prime, but there is one with $|Aut(G)|=p^{12}$.

For the abelian case: There is no group $G$ such that $Aut(G)\cong C_n$ for $n>1$ odd, see [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwjuv6bhjpjMAhVsCpoKHR35D84QFghCMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.emis.de%2Fjournals%2FMPRIA%2F2004%2Fpa104i2%2Fpdf%2F104a211.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEozjTtDGr5d-UFMqtsPVvcGZclxA&sig2=1EVWTpb7BdY6i5GQejy5oQ&bvm=bv.119745492,d.bGs). A full classification of abelian groups occuring as automorphism groups of finite groups is still not known.